# What is the source of the humming sound in my shower?

Tags: bathroom, water, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I have a Grohe shower with a mixing tap (sorry if this is not the correct English word - what I have is [similar to this](https://www.grohe.fr/fr_fr/pour-la-salle-de-bains/collections/mitigeurs%20thermostatiques/grohtherm-3000-cosmopolitan.html), with a [fixed shower head](https://www.grohe.fr/fr_fr/for-your-bathroom/collections/hand-showers-and-shower-sets/tempesta-headshower.html) and a removable one).

It works fine for about 5 years now but since recently I started to hear an extra sound when taking my shower. I think this is best described as a "humming sound", very different from the one the falling water makes. It is faint but I can hear it from outside the bathroom, when I do not hear the falling water anymore.

It looks like the sound ("music") water would make running though a loose seal (wildly guessing)

**What can be the source of such a sound in the case of a mixer tap?**

I am sure this must be the tap because I can hear the sound independently of the shower head that it used (they are both connected directly to the tap)

Comment: Someone who doesn’t know the words to the song?

Comment: Yes, mixing tap makes good sense, and your hypothesis of a loose part is likely correct. A washer could be loose... but another possibility is excessive pressure, more likely if you have your own well rather than use a community water supply. See https://www.ehow.co.uk/facts_5017210_causes-water-pipes-hum.html